# jquery mobile get value from input

Tags: jquery-mobile, input

I'm trying get the value from a input but it doesn't work

I have:

```
<input id="inputA" name="inputA" type="number" value="25" />
```

and:

```
var pot = $('#inputA').val();
```

Also, I have tried:

```
var pot = $('#inputA').text();
```

But it doesn't work.

I need help please!

Answer (score -2):

Try to console `$('#inputA')` before you get its value, if it undefined, may be this document will help you http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.1/docs/api/events.html